# MarkLogic 8 - XQuery - cts:search - Change database programmatically

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I change the database that a `cts:search` function runs against programmatically?

Right now I'm in query console.

Answer (score 6):

You will probably need to use `xdmp:eval`, which accepts an options argument, and in there you can specify the database:

```
xdmp:eval("cts:search(...)",  (),
   <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
     <database>{xdmp:database("otherdb")}</database>
   </options>)
```

Comment: This is not only a good answer, but it's probably the only correct one.  Your only options of specifying which DB to query, that I know of, are: `xdmp:eval` family, `xdmp:invoke` family, and `xdmp:spawn` family.

Answer (score 2):

Although on the lowest level, xdmp:eval is really what happens, the most clean option which is probably easiest to write inline is [xdmp:invoke-function](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:invoke-function)- and even better may be to also use an anonymous function within it. This combination allows for natural use of existing variables. If you want to go further, then also look at xdmp:apply(to add more flexability)

Furthermore, in MarkLogic 8, there is a new transaction-type called *update-auto-commit* which also makes it nice and clean to invoke a function inline, while waiting for the results (no spawn) and have it in its own transaction. Used properly, then the results of an update/insert are even available in the calling code.

**The code sample below applies cts:search against another database and
   naturally uses the variables in the main code:**

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

let $query := cts:word-query("foo")
let $start := 1
let $end := 3
let $database-name := "your-other-database-name-here"

 return
    xdmp:invoke-function(
      function() { 
          cts:search(doc(), $query)[$start to $end]        
      },
      <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
        <database>{xdmp:database($database-name)}</database>
      </options>)
```